# Reading the parameters of the executable

Tags: c, parameter-passing

in my program I will use two parameters. It could look like this:

```
./myApp -status 7 -file abc.txt
```

My question is how to make conditions like "if(parameter_status==7)" and how to get to abc.txt from -file in my main?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long int status = 0;
char *filename = NULL;

for (i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
  if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-status")) {
    status = strtol(argv[++i], NULL, 10);
  } else if (!strcmp(argv[i], "-file")) {
    filename = argv[++i];
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the "&& i < argc - 1" for?

Answer (score 3):

Use the GNU C Library getopt() call. An example of how to use it is at [www.gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt).

Answer (score 2):

The parameters you pass through command line reside at argv param of main(), their count is in argc.